# How to get the brach name from a bitbucket PR trigger in Tekton?

Tags: tekton, tekton-pipelines

I'm building a Tekton pipeline where I need to get all the modified files in a PR. This pipeline is initiated by a Bitbucket Pull Request web hook. The problem is the web hook payload includes the commit hash, but not the branch. So I have a task to [clone the repo](https://hub.tekton.dev/tekton/Task/git-clone/0.9), but I can't pass the branch name to that task since that information isn't provided from the payload. According to Tekton, these are the variables I have available to me from the `bitbucket-pullreq` trigger:

```
gitrepo-url
pullreq-sha
pullreq-state
pullreq-number
pullreq-repo-name
pullreq-html-url
pullreq-title
user-type
```

I can get the branch name from the PR # by using the Bitbucket API. Is there a way to set that branch name as a variable so that I can clone the correct branch in another task? Similar to Ansible's `set_fact` module.

My other option is to build a custom task to query the Bitbucket API for the branch name, then checkout that branch and do what I need to do, but I'd rather not do that if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized instead of finding the branch name I can check out the commit hash instead of the branch:

```yaml
params:
  - name: url
    value: $(params.gitrepo-url)
  - name: revision
    value: $(params.pullreq-sha)
```